# Evaluate the integral that gives the area in the first quadrant between the circles

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral that gives the area in the first quadrant between the circles 
$$x^2 + y^2 = 400 \quad \text and \quad x^2 - 20x + y^2 = 0$$

I think the angle should range from $0$ to $\pi/2$,
I'm not sure how to find the range for $r$ and how to set up the inside integral.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It's good to learn some typesetting of equations and formulas, at least in the long run. Also if something looks like a homework question you are encouraged to show what you've tried. Showing some own work will probably increase the chances of getting good response.

Comment: Hint: switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Did you at least plot the two circles?

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting equation (1) from (2),

$x^2 - 20x + y^2 -x^2 - y^2 = 0 - 400$

$-20x = -400$

$x = 20$

So range from 0 to 20.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2=400$ is a circle of radius 20 centered at the origin.  Area in the QI = $\frac 14 \pi 20^2$
$x^2+y^2=20x$ is a circle of radius 10 centered (0,10).  Area in Q I $= \frac12 \pi 10^2$

$50 \pi$

If you want to use calculus:

$\int_{0}^{20} \sqrt{20^2-x^2} - \sqrt{20x-x^2} dx\\\int_{0}^{20} \sqrt{20^2 - x^2} - \int_{0}^{20} \sqrt{10 - (x-10)^2} dx$

Tackle each with a slightly different substitution.

For the one on the left:

$x = 20 \sin u, dx = 20 \cos u \ du $

and the one on the right:

$x-10 = 10\sin v, dx = 10\cos v\ dv$

$\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} 20^2\cos^2 u\ du - \int_{0}^{\pi} 10^2\cos^2 v \ dv$

$(\frac 12) 20^2 \frac {\pi}{2} - (\frac 12) 10^2 \pi$